# How To Handle Event On Dynamic Parent Child Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still not statisfy regarding Dynamic Child Inside Dynamic Parent where a lot of confusing for me and more worst how to know which once and how I can manipulate them to what I want.

For yours informations I am very very new on Javascript and Jquery, but I can catch up if someone give a right directions and a rights syntax. I love clean code where from that code I can learn more and understand.

Let say I have this structure html where it's same on firebugs:-

```
<div name="div0" class="div0">
<input name="txt0" class="txt0">
<br/><br/>
<div name="div1[]" class="divL1">
    <button class="btn1"></button>
    <button class="btn2"></button>
    <input  name="txtL1_a[]" class="cLtxt1">
    <input  name="txtL1_b[]" class="cLtxt1">
             <br/><br/>
             <div name="div2[]" class="divL2">
                  <div id="ui-widget">
                  <input  name="txtL2_a[]" class="cLtxt2 autosuggest">
                  </div>
                  <input  name="txtL2_b[]" class="cLtxt2">
             </div>
     <br/><br/>
<div name="div1[]" class="divL1">
    <button class="btn1"></button>
    <button class="btn2"></button>
    <input  name="txtL1_a[]" class="cLtxt1">
    <input  name="txtL1_b[]" class="cLtxt1">
             <br/><br/>
             <div name="div2[]" class="divL2">
                  <div id="ui-widget">
                  <input  name="txtL2_a[]" class="cLtxt2 autosuggest">
                  </div>
                  <input  name="txtL2_b[]" class="cLtxt2">
             </div>                 
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

Actually on my head have a lot of question but let me ask a few question first.

**1.** I want to run .autosuggest where it's complicated for me because on normal form before this I can manage run it, but when .autosuggest inside dynamic parent div and located on dynamic input I cannot get a value and show a autocomplete.

By given id "txtL2_a[]" function SearchText cannot performance autocomplete and don't know which index are doing that.

```
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "frmsetuptrip.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    minLength: 3,
                    data: "{'presearch':'" + document.getElementById('txtL2_a[]').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if ((data.d).length == 0) {
                            //$('#button9').show();
                            var result = [
   {
       label: 'No matches found',
       value: response.term
   }
                            ];
                            response(result);
                        }
                        else {
                            response(data.d);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

**2.** Let say on

```
<div name="div1[]" class="divL1"> //index 1
```

I need some auto fill up - let say when I fill up

```
<input  name="txtL2_a[]" class="cLtxt2 autosuggest">  //index :1
```

automatically value inside

```
<input  name="txtL2_b[]" class="cLtxt2"> 'Index 1
```

will change only based parents index.

**3.** There is anyway a one function where I can catch all event and elaborate that by IF before go specific sub function or task like this pseudo code below:-

```
    $("div.div0").each(function (event) {

    if (event=="keyup" on child=="divL1"+index[0]){
       //detect more spesific which object are doing that
        if (whoisdoing=="txtL1_a[]"+index[0] {
          //then do action etc: fill up parent input
          $("div0.txt0").val($(txtL1_a.index[0]).val());  
        }
        if (whoisdoing=="txtL1_b[]"+index[0] {
         //then do action etc: fill up childs input 
          $("div2[index[0]].txtL2_b[index[0]].val( $(txtL1_b[index[0]]).val() );
        }
    }

//event - keypress

//event - click

//and many more

    });
```

I cannot find on internet regarding all this matter I mention above. If anybody have a solution or already develop that function please sharing and I believe this is not easy to handle.

Anyway thanks on advance to you for reading and replying my question.

Best Regards.

Comment: Your html is so invalid, even http://jsbeautifier.org/ can't correct it

Comment: Thanks you for pointing that, please let see again my html structure after I do editing if your really want to helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I think and think again - it's should be have an solution!

Rights now I can handle KEYUP and Click on my dynamic child which specific input tag where I can do some task. I found on dynamic child inside dynamic parent I need use direct Class Name and Catch Parent Index first.

You cannot use this syntax below for my html structure:-

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
        var buttonsLength = buttons.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < buttonsLength; i++) {
            buttons[i].addEventListener('keyup', clickResponse, false);
        };
    });
    function clickResponse() {
        //  do something based on button selection here...
    }
```

I found above syntax only can run on first level Parent only without dynamic child/parent add on run time.

What I do is using this syntax below **to solve my problem number 2 and 3**.

```
        $("div.div0").on("keyup", "input", function () {
            //detect name and val which input are doing keyup
            handler = $(this).val();
            name = $(this).attr('name');
            parHandler = name;
            //only this input I want do some task
            if (name == "txtL1_a[]") {
                dcAction = "FillUpOtherInput";
                FillUp; //run functions                   
            }
        });

        function FillUp() { 
            if (dcAction == "FillUpOtherInput") {
                alert("Handler Name: " + parHandler + " Index Level :" + dc2);
                //make sure right Parent Index before insert a value
                //--should i loop
                $("div.purchase-items").each(function (i) {
                    alert(i);
                    if (i == dc2) {
                        $(this).find("input[name='txtL1_b[]']").val("Hai");
                    }
                    i+1
                });
                parHandler = "";
                dc2 = "";
                dcAction = "";
            }
        }
```

Yes! I can fill up value to other input on same Parent Index.

If anybody have problem regarding Dynamic Child inside Dynamic Parent on do action like me, yours can refer this syntax to solve your problem.

If anyone have better solutions please share here to help other person like me as newbie on Jquery functions.

Answer (score 1):

For question No 1 regarding autocomplete where is detect which dynamic child are doing I use this line syntax:-

```
    function SearchText(pIndex,iValue) {
        //alert(dc2 + "/" + iValue);
        $("div.divL2").eq(pIndex).find(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "frmsetuptrip.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    minLength: 3,
                    data: "{'presearch':'" + $("div.divL2").eq(pIndex).find("input[name='txtL2_a[]']").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if ((data.d).length == 0) {
                            //$('#button9').show();
                            var result = [
   {
       label: 'No matches found',
       value: response.term
   }
                            ];
                            response(result);
                        }
                        else {
                            response(data.d);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Now my autocomplete can catch txtL2_a[] value and know which parent are to show a list.

What I learn and like to share to yours is a key

*$("div.divL2").eq(pIndex).find(".autosuggest")*

**$(-what is parent name-).eq(-put parent index-).find(-class name on input-)**

then it's should be run!.

I am new and must thanks to all who read this question and hope someone can get some idea from what I wrote up here. 
Who's are trying intentionally to help me like **@baao** I really appreciate it and many thanks.

Yours are welcome to share if any better syntax/script on this matter to put on, maybe it's can help a thousand out there are search and face a problem same like me.

And I am glad and honest to share my code what I already know and solving a matter regarding my situations.

Answer (score 0):

To make shorter syntax on fillup function follow this below:-

```
function FillUp() { 
            if (dcAction == "FillUpOtherInput") { 
                $(div.div0).eq(dc2).find("input[name='txtL1_b[]']").val("Hai");
                parHandler = "";
                dc2 = "";
                dcAction = "";
            }
        }
```

I just know **eq(***if you know the index***)** are direct go to specific element like dynamic parent/child based index given.